# De-serializing object using TCP

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, deserialization, objectinputstream

I am trying to code a basic TCP server that has an `Object` called `Person` sent to it from a single client. I have gotten the connection working and an `Object` sent to the server. However, whenever I try to convert the read `Object` back into a `Person` (person class exists for client and server), the server throws a `ClassNotFoundException`. The problem is on the following line of code

```
Person person = (Person)in.readObject();
```

Here is the Server Class:

```
public class ConnectionTestServer extends Thread {

private ServerSocket server;
private Socket client;
private BufferedReader reader;


@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket( 25565 );
        client = server.accept();
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream( client.getInputStream() );

        while ( true ){ 
            System.out.println(in.toString());//This was for debug
            if(in.readObject() instanceof Person){//and this
            System.out.println("Working?");
            }
            Person person = (Person)in.readObject();//Here is the ClassNotFoundException
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ConnectionTestServer().start();

}
}
```

Here is the Client Class:

```
public class ConnectionTestClient {

private static Socket server;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        server = new Socket("localhost", 25565);

        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream( server.getOutputStream() );
        stream.writeObject( new Person() );
        stream.flush();

        server.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

And finally the Person Class:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
 public int id = 10;
}
```

If anyone can help me with this problem, I'll appreciate it. Also, some general advice over my (probably) bad coding would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: You can also import `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem before when deserializing a object from TCP;

**solution:**

You need to put the Person class on the same name package in server and in client

example:

**server**
com.utilities -> person class in that folder

**client**
com.utilities -> person class in that folder

also generate a `serialVersionUID`.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree to Rod_Algonquin. I would like to add to it, for your specific problem.

There are few things you need to do,

1. Like Rob said, Both server's and client's `Person` objects must be in the same package and with similar *`serialvesrionUID`*.
2. Your code for the server should be as follows: (Observe the lines commented, **in your code you are reading the object twice while sending it only once**)

   ```
   public class Server extends Thread {

   private ServerSocket server;
   private Socket client;


   @Override
   public void run() {
   try {
       server = new ServerSocket(25565);
       client = server.accept();



       while (true) {
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
           ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
           System.out.println(in.toString());// This was for debug

           /*if (in.readObject() instanceof Person) {// and this
               System.out.println("Working?");
           }*/

           Person person = (Person) in.readObject();
           System.out.println(person.id);
           // Here is the
                                                       // ClassNotFoundException
       }

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```
3. Plus a suggestion, in java socket programming you should use `BufferInputStream`/ `BufferedOutputStream` while reading/ writing multiple objects. It leads to better performance.